# How to move a element from one frame to another

Tags: forms, excel, vba

On Excel forms or vb:

lets say i have frame1 with a button on it, it serves me well for a state for a certain workflow, but later on the same flow i would like the same button to appear on frame2 because according to the state a change the layout of the main form.
is this possible?

Comment: I already tried  btn.parent = bt2.parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** OK, my previous answer failed. How about the [SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call?

```
Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild _
  As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long

Call SetParent(btn.hWnd, Frame2.hWnd)
```

---

*Old answer, doesn't work*

*Did you try `Set btn.parent = frame2`*

*You need the Set*

Comment: It didnt work my friend, I ended up replicating the buttons and put the the event code in generic functions that will be called with some parameters that I will receieve, not the cleanest solution but I guess is better than getting stuck

Comment: With the new answer, did you get any error message, or just nothing happens? I tried it in a test project and it worked for me.

Comment: Im gettint object does not support his method

Comment: btw im suing vba on excel 2003

Comment: VBA? I don't think you can do this in VBA. My second answer works in VB6, but AFAICR most VBA controls are windowless (don't have hWnd properties)

Comment: I see, well thats good to know... It's kinda weird as if you think about it the complexity of such action isnt that high. But oh well, kudos to MS

Answer (score 0):

If your button present on the same frame then its not possible if your button is present on out side of